# LinearLayout has invalid child element android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: xamarin, android-recyclerview, visual-studio-2017

I was developing an android app using VS2017 Xamarin. As I try to use a RecyclerView, it says LinearLayout has invalid child element `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`. The axml code is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

FYI, I have added the nuget package Version 23.1.1 and set the android application settings accordingly. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the code itself it doesn't seem like the layout is invalid. You can check out the sample code [for Xamarin.Android RecyclerView](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android5.0/RecyclerViewer) to test out if it works on your machine.

I would suggest trying to access the `Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView` from code to see if the type is actually available, because it seems more likely that it has installed improperly.

In Visual Studio go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Management Console . In the Package Manager Console window then enter the following command:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

This will force-reinstall NuGet packages in your solution to make sure they are actually installed properly. Please also check if the V7 Support package is actually listed under you Android project references.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to access it from code and it is accessible. I think it doesnt want to be a child of the linearlayout. So I removed the linear layout and took   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" to the recyclerview tag. Now the error is different and it says The 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView' element is not declared.

Comment: That shouldn't be the issue - if you check out the sample you can see they use the exact same approach, end even I have used it myself several times - https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android5.0/RecyclerViewer/RecyclerViewer/Resources/layout/Main.axml . It must some hidden catch :-O

Comment: I have found that this might just be a Visual Studio issue and restarting it might help: https://talk.remobjects.com/t/70237-closed-compiler-warning-linearlayout-has-invalid-child-element-imagebutton/5181/4

Comment: Also, please try deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders from the Android project folder

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. But reinstalling visual studio is gonna take me much time so that will be the last option. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, something must work. And please try the sample project if it works there

Comment: I uninstalled the recyclerview package and all other nugets that I installed and reinstall only the Xamarin.android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView Version 23.1.1 which installs Xamarin.android.support.v4 as a prerequisite. The error didnt go. Then I watched some videos on youtube, and came back to the Visual Studio, and the error was gone. Atleast I should have known the real reason but I think its the deleting of other packages and reinstalling of only the necessay nugets with appropriate versions. @Martin Zikmund, Thanks for hanging around and providing useful suggestions.